# How to get location without internet using intent service?

Tags: android, android-gps, android-intentservice

I don't want to use service which is continuously running in background ! Actually in my project user will send SMS command from any smartphone to his/her misplaced smartphone.My app will detect that particular "SMS command" and in return it will send the current location of misplaced mobile.
can it be done through intent service ? I m damn confused ... Its single time operation how to perform it efficiently ... ?

Comment: use GPS service

Comment: can you provide any link or code ?

Comment: can you please be more descriptive with adding code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: or use NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: bro I told you I have no idea how to start but I am sure it should be done via background service ! its single time operation therefore probably intent service should be used ...

Comment: yaa i read your question.In android we can get location 3 ways GPS,Internet and mobile Network provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `NETWORK_PROVIDER`  getting geolocation

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and add this permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: should I copy this code in intent service then call this intent service in broadcast receiver ?

Comment: I think your app must run in  background for finding SMS Command .If command found you simply send geolocation that number

Comment: I have done that job "finding SMS Command" I have used incoming SMS broadcast receiver for it blah blah ...  do I just need to call ur code from broadcast receiver that's it ?